# Get current quarter in year with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, date, datetime

How can I get the current quarter we are in with javascript? I am trying to detect what quarter we are currently in, e.g. 2.

**EDIT** And how can I count the number of days left in the quarter?

Comment: What are your criteria for [quarter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_year)? In some cases, they are Jan to Dec, others Jul to Jun the following year, and so on. And they may not align with months.

Comment: Approximate is fine, if it is a day off it isn't the end of the world, however if there is another way to get the current quarter without depending on the month that would be ideal.

Comment: This may help you [Stack answer with fiddle][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20989200/2837412

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Given that you haven't provided any criteria for how to determine what quarter "*we are currently in", an algorithm can be suggested that you must then adapt to whatever criteria you need. e.g.

```
// For the US Government fiscal year
// Oct-Dec = 1
// Jan-Mar = 2
// Apr-Jun = 3
// Jul-Sep = 4
function getQuarter(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var m = Math.floor(d.getMonth()/3) + 2;
  return m > 4? m - 4 : m;
}
```

As a runnable snippet and including the year:

```js
function getQuarter(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var m = Math.floor(d.getMonth() / 3) + 2;
  m -= m > 4 ? 4 : 0;
  var y = d.getFullYear() + (m == 1? 1 : 0);
  return [y,m];
}

console.log(`The current US fiscal quarter is ${getQuarter().join('Q')}`);
console.log(`1 July 2018 is ${getQuarter(new Date(2018,6,1)).join('Q')}`);
```

You can then adapt that to the various financial or calendar quarters as appropriate. You can also do:

```
function getQuarter(d) {
  d = d || new Date(); // If no date supplied, use today
  var q = [4,1,2,3];
  return q[Math.floor(d.getMonth() / 3)];
}
```

Then use different `q` arrays depending on the definition of quarter required.

#### Edit

The following gets the days remaining in a quarter if they start on 1 Jan, Apr, Jul and Oct, It's tested in various browsers, including IE 6 (though since it uses basic ECMAScript it should work everywhere):

```
function daysLeftInQuarter(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var qEnd = new Date(d);
  qEnd.setMonth(qEnd.getMonth() + 3 - qEnd.getMonth() % 3, 0);
  return Math.floor((qEnd - d) / 8.64e7);
}
```

Comment: `$NaN`? I have no idea how you get that, the code above is tested in Firefox and IE 9, it's plain ECMAScript so has nothing to do with jQuery. All of it should work in nearly every browser that ever supported javascript, certainly everything since and including IE and NN 4.

Comment: yeah yeah it's cool it was an issue with ie 6, and sadly the client I'm building this for can't "upgrade" to like chrome or something.

Comment: Your daysleftInquarter example isn't correct, it keeps returning 60 when I pass the current month

Comment: Your very first code block returns 0 for a date in Dec due to getMonth being a 0 based index.

Comment: @TonyGutierrez—Thanks, error is due to my bad Mathematics, it should have been `m - 4` not `m - 5`.

Comment: so where does year come into this? surely Q1 of 2018 doesn't come after Q3 of 2018!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver—added a runnable snippet with year.

Comment: @RobG thanks but what I meant was the function could return a tuple { quarter, year } where for Q1 the year is actually calendarDate.Year + 1 since it belongs to the next year. If people don’t do that and sort the data they’ll get a huge mess!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver—the new function returns `[y,m]`. ;-) Formatting of the actual expression is up to the user, if sortability is required then year/quarter suits. My preference is 2019Q1, which is quite ISO-ish, so probably why the US seem to prefer something else, like Q1'19 or Q1/19 or similar that will not sort lexically. :-(

Comment: omg, why so difficult? Why do you all use floor and add 1, when you can simply use ceil?
`return Math.ceil((d.getMonth() + 1) / 3)`

Answer (score 97):

Assuming January through March are considered Q1 (some countries/companies separate their financial year from their calendar year), the following code should work:

```
var today = new Date();
var quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
```

This gives you:

```
Month      getMonth()  quarter
---------  ----------  -------
January         0         1
February        1         1
March           2         1
April           3         2
May             4         2
June            5         2
July            6         3
August          7         3
September       8         3
October         9         4
November       10         4
December       11         4
```

As to how to get the days remaining in the quarter, it's basically figuring out the first day of the next quarter and working out the difference, something like:

```
var today = new Date();
var quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
var nextq;
if (quarter == 4) {
    nextq = new Date (today.getFullYear() + 1, 1, 1);
} else {
    nextq = new Date (today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
}
var millis1 = today.getTime();
var millis2 = nextq.getTime();
var daydiff = (millis2 - millis1) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

That's untested but the theory is sound. Basically create a date corresponding to the next quarter, convert it and today into milliseconds since the start of the epoch, then the difference is the number of milliseconds.

Divide that by the number of milliseconds in a day and you have the difference in days.

That gives you (at least roughly) number of days left in the quarter. You may need to fine-tune it to ensure all *times* are set to the same value (00:00:00) so that the difference is in exact days.

It may also be off by one, depending on your actual definition of "days left in the quarter".

But it should be a good starting point.

Comment: Given that the OP thinks August is in Q2, it is unlikely January to March is Q1. A hard coded solution works though.

Comment: @Rob, I saw the example 2 as just being a quarter we _could_ be in. I don't think the OP is stating that it corresponds to the current month when this question was asked (August).

Comment: Surely you need a Math.floor around your result to get the quarter? Also there is no variable called "now", I guess you meant to use "today" instead?

Comment: @lee_mcmullen, hence the "untested" comment :-) Congrats on being the first person to pick up the `today/now` error in over a year, have fixed both issues based on your suggestions.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks it helped me . do you know how to calcualte FYTD and CYTD same like above ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909656/caluclate-start-date-and-end-date-for-fiscal-year-to-date-fytd-and-cytd-calen

Comment: Original answer did not account for dates in North America where one is in Daylight savings and the other is not. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveSeeger, not sure what you're talking about there, the *quarter* is dictated by month alone. Daylight savings doesn't seem to be the least bit relevant here, you're either in a month or not. Perhaps you could explain further?

Comment: @paxdiablo I added an edit which accounts for daylight savings. This refers to the second part of the answer, days remaining in the quarter. I used this in production but had to account for DST. This is because today and nextq dates can have time zone vales that differ by one hour. In this case, daydiff will not be an integer and be off by one hour eg 1\24th.

Comment: Steve: Ah, that makes sense now. Let me have a look at it, not sure why the swarm rejected it if it was valid.

Answer (score 8):

```
function getQuarter(d) {
  return Math.floor(d.getMonth()/3) + 1);
}
```

EDIT: i left out %4, totally right, thanks Clement

Comment: % 4 is not needed

Answer (score 7):

if the first solution doesn't work than you can just adjust it to the range you would like

```
var today = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth();
var quarter;
if (month < 4)
  quarter = 1;
else if (month < 7)
  quarter = 2;
else if (month < 10)
  quarter = 3;
else if (month < 13)
  quarter = 4;
```

Comment: Since month is zero-based, 4/7/10/13 should be 3/6/9/12

Answer (score 5):

You can use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) package:

Answer of your question using moment package is:

```
moment().quarter()
```

Below are the start and end dates of a quarter using the moment package:

**START DATE OF QUARTER**

```
moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the current quarter with the date set to the quarter starting date.

```
moment("2019", "YYYY").quarter(4).startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the starting date of the 4th quarter of the year "2019".

```
moment().startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the starting date of the current quarter of current year.

**END DATE OF QUARTER**

```
moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).endOf('quarter');
```

Would return the current quarter with the date set to quarter ending date.

```
moment("2019", "YYYY").quarter(4).endOf('quarter');
```

Would return the ending date of the 4th quarter of the year "2019".

```
moment().endOf('quarter');
```

Would return the ending date of the current quarter of current year.

Answer (score 4):

Depend on month

```
 var date = new Date();     
 var quarter =  parseInt(date.getMonth() / 3 ) + 1 ;
```

Depend on Date

```
 var date = new Date();    
 var firstday = new Date(date.getFullYear(),0,1); // XXXX/01/01
 var diff = Math.ceil((date - firstday) / 86400000); 
 // a quarter is about 365/4 
 quarter =  parseInt( diff / ( 365/ 4 )) + 1 
 // if today is 2012/01/01, the value of quarter  is  1.
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me!

```js
var d = new Date();
var quarter = Math.ceil(d.getMonth() / 3);

console.log(quarter)
```

Comment: Just what I'm looking for, as I wanted to have the actual Quarter, not the US fiscal year. Thanks!

Comment: Since the month is zero-based, you'll need to add 1 for this to work properly.

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11].map(month => Math.ceil(month/3)) === [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

Answer (score 1):

Universal, fast performance (no division, no floats), easy modified for other standard

```js
const now = new Date()
const currentMonth = now.getMonth() + 1
const currentQuarter = {
   1: 1, // January
   2: 1, // February
   3: 1, // March

   4: 2, // April
   5: 2, // May
   6: 2, // June

   7: 3, // July
   8: 3, // August
   9: 3, // September

   10: 4, // October
   11: 4, // November
   12: 4, // December
}[currentMonth]

console.log(currentQuarter)
```

Comment: I agree.  Dealing with integers is much faster than dealing with floating point numbers, especially if you have a large dataset that you need to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you all use floor, when you can simply use `ceil`.

```js
function getQuarter(m) {
  return Math.ceil(m / 3)
}

// Test it
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].map(getQuarter);
```

If month counts from 0, just add 1 to month number:

```js
function getQuarter(date) {
  const m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  return Math.ceil(m / 3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not efficient or readable but it's in oneliner flavour.

```
(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), Math.floor((new Date().getMonth() + 3) / 3) * 3, 1) - new Date()) / 86400000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set Period Function
  SetPeriod(SelectedVal) {
    try {
      if (SelectedVal === '0') { return; }
      if (SelectedVal != null) {
        let yrf: number, mtf: number, dyf: number, yrt: number, mtt: number, dyt: number, dtf: any, dtt: any;
        let dat = new Date();
        let q = 0;
        switch (SelectedVal) {
          case '-1': // Not specify
            frm = ''; to = '';
            return;
          case '0': // As specify
            break;
          case '1': // This Month
            yrf = yrt = dat.getUTCFullYear();
            mtf = mtt = dat.getUTCMonth();
            dyf = 1; dyt = this.getDaysInMonth(mtf, yrf);
            break;
          case '2': // Last Month
            dat.setDate(0); // 0 will result in the last day of the previous month
            dat.setDate(1); // 1 will result in the first day of the month
            yrf = yrt = dat.getUTCFullYear();
            mtf = mtt = dat.getUTCMonth();
            dyf = 1; dyt = this.getDaysInMonth(mtf, yrf);
            break;
          case '3': // This quater
            q = Math.ceil((dat.getUTCMonth()) / 3);
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-switch-case-fall-through
          case '4': // Last quater
            if (q === 0) { q = Math.ceil(dat.getUTCMonth() / 3) - 1; if (q === 0) { q = 1; } }
            yrf = yrt = dat.getUTCFullYear();
            if (q === 1) {
              mtf = 0; mtt = 2;
              dyf = 1; dyt = 31;
            } else if (q === 2) {
              mtf = 3; mtt = 5;
              dyf = 1; dyt = 30;
            } else if (q === 3) {
              mtf = 6; mtt = 8;
              dyf = 1; dyt = 30;
            } else if (q === 4) {
              mtf = 9; mtt = 11;
              dyf = 1; dyt = 31;
            }
            break;
          case '6': // Last year
            dat = new Date(dat.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1);
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-switch-case-fall-through
          case '5': // This year
            yrf = yrt = dat.getUTCFullYear();
            mtf = 0; mtt = 11;
            dyf = 1; dyt = 31;
            break;
        }

        // Convert to new Date
        dtf = new Date(yrf, mtf, dyf);
        dtt = new Date(yrt, mtt, dyt);
        console.log('dtf', dtf);
        console.log('dtt', dtt);

      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }



// Get Day in Month
  getDaysInMonth = (month: number, year: number) => {
    return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, quarter depends on the input quarter start date (month, day) and quarter duration (3, 6)

```
function getCurrentQuarter(startDateString, quarterDuration) {
    var startDate = new Date(startDateString)
    // default order of months
    var months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    let startMonth = startDate.getMonth() + 1
    let startMonthIndex = months.indexOf(startMonth)
    // rotate months to get start month first
    if (startMonthIndex != 0) {
        var monthsNew = months.slice(startMonthIndex, months.length)
        months = monthsNew.concat(months.slice(0, startMonthIndex))
    }
    
    let today = new Date()
    let thisMonth = today.getMonth() + 1
    let thisMonthIndex = months.indexOf(thisMonth) + 1
    // compare with date
    let thisDay = today.getDate()
    let startDay = startDate.getDate()
    if (thisDay < startDay) {
        // this is previous month
        if (thisMonthIndex == 1) {
            thisMonthIndex = 12
        } else {
            thisMonthIndex = thisMonthIndex - 1
        }
    }
    // find quarter
    let thisQuarter = Math.ceil(thisMonthIndex / quarterDuration)

    return thisQuarter
}
```

> getCurrentQuarter('2021-03-15', 3)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who cares about the Fiscal Quarter, and many do, here's a simple way that requires 0(1) time.  First, since this is fixed data based on month, why not just create an associative array?  Remember, JavaScript months start with 0 and go to 11.

```
** getMonth(): Fiscal quarter

const FISCAL_QUARTER = {
   0:2,1:2,2:2,3:3,4:3,5:3,6:4,7:4,8:4,9:1,10:1,11:1
};
function getFiscalQuarter(d){   
   return FISCAL_QUARTER[d.getMonth()];
}
console.log(getFiscalQuarter(new Date()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take

```js
var todayDate = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
var currentQuarter = Math.floor(todayDate.getMonth() / 3);
var firstDate = new Date(
  new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), currentQuarter * 3, 1).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
);
var endDate = new Date(
  new Date(
    firstDate.getFullYear(),
    firstDate.getMonth() + 3,
    0
  ).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
);
console.log(endDate)
```