# DateFormat to display quarter number on Google Annotation Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using [Google Annotation chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) to display data daily, weekly, monthly &  quarterly.

The option set as -

```
dateFormat: 'Wee&#107; w, MMM yyyy'
```

for weekly data. It is working for daily `d MMM yyyy` & for monthly `MMM yyyy` also.

But I am not finding any way to display the quarter number. Looked into [Javascript Date](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) also, no result.

[image]

Want to display quarter number according to the date. Any help would be appreciated.

**Sample Data**

```
[
[new Date(2014, 10 - 1, 01), 615, 0, 615],
[new Date(2015, 01 - 1, 01), 5142, 0, 5142],
[new Date(2015, 04 - 1, 01), 8785, 0, 8785],
[new Date(2015, 07 - 1, 01), 11919, 914, 11005],
[new Date(2015, 10 - 1, 01), 14646, 2044, 12602],
[new Date(2016, 01 - 1, 01), 15801, 2426, 13375]
]
```

Comment: don't think there is a way, in JavaScript, to _format_ a date as quarter, but it could be [calculated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11981763/5090771) and added as a column...

Comment: @WhiteHat Yup, it can be calculated. But Google chart wants the format to be displayed and the dates are passed to the chart as date object.

Comment: could you share a sample of the data for testing?

Comment: @WhiteHat Check the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking through the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart#configuration-options) for `dateFormat`...
google has provided a way to format dates as *Quarter*....

> The format used to display the date information in the top right corner. The format of this field is as specified by the [java SimpleDateFormat class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

*SimpleDateFormat* does include options for *Quarter*, see the link.

you can simply use...
`dateFormat: 'Q'` -- *Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4*

or...
`dateFormat: 'QQQQ'` -- *1st quarter, 2nd quarter, 3rd quarter, 4th quarter*

example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Data Capture');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Contacts Lost');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Net Contact');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2014, 10 - 1, 01), 615, 0, 615],
    [new Date(2015, 01 - 1, 01), 5142, 0, 5142],
    [new Date(2015, 04 - 1, 01), 8785, 0, 8785],
    [new Date(2015, 07 - 1, 01), 11919, 914, 11005],
    [new Date(2015, 10 - 1, 01), 14646, 2044, 12602],
    [new Date(2016, 01 - 1, 01), 15801, 2426, 13375]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {
    dateFormat: 'Q',
    displayAnnotations: true
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I know there is no option to display the date in quarter format. I am just looking for an workaround.

Comment: My Bad. I have checked that but with a typo. Working. Thanks.