# List of quarters between a particular day and today

Tags: javascript, list, date

I need a simple help. I wuold like to have a function that generate an array (or a list) of quarters between two dates, in JavaScript. The first one is fixed, while the second date is today.

For example: I wish I have a list of quarters between the first day of 2016 and today. So I would like to have this kind of list

```
{Gen-Feb-Mar 2016,
Apr-May-June 2016,
Jul-Ago-Sep 2016,
Oct-Nov-Dec 2016,
Gen-Feb-Mar 2017}
```

The final purpose is to put it into a combo selection.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can help, show us what you have so far.

Comment: might want to take a look at this library: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: You could start by working out the quarter for a particular date, see [*Get current quarter in year with javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981453/get-current-quarter-in-year-with-javascript). What have you tried?

Comment: Combine @RobG's link with [get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates) and you have yourself an answer.

Comment: Thanks to all of you that helped me! 
Ultimately I chose the solution of @Joseph Marikle for the reason that fits more easily to the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to build the list you have here, you can iterate over the difference of the start year to the current year and then calculate the current quarter with `parseInt(new Date().getMonth() / 3 + 1)`

```js
var d = new Date(),
  y = d.getFullYear(),
  m = d.getMonth(),
  quarters = ['Jan-Feb-Mar', 'Apr-May-Jun', 'Jul-Aug-Sep', 'Oct-Nov-Dec'],
  options = [];

for (var pastYear = 2016; pastYear < y; pastYear++) {
  quarters.forEach(q => options.push(q + ' ' + pastYear));
}
quarters.slice(0, parseInt(m / 3 + 1)).forEach(q => options.push(q + ' ' + y));

console.log("current date: " + d);
console.log(options);
```

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution. Just one thing, I deleted the +1 from the 'parseInt(m/3 + 1)' because I need only quarters ended ;)

Comment: @Lorenzo You're welcome.  Glad I could help, and good work on finding what was needed to adapt it to your needs.  I was a little worried about readability. :P

Answer (score 1):

Assuming quarters are sections of 3 months, so Jan-Mar is Q1, Apr-Jun is Q2 etc. then you can simply work out the quarter of the start date, then just keep adding 3 months until you get to the quarter of the last date.

Quarters can be represented as yyyyQq, e.g. 15 June 2017 is 2017Q2. Calculating the quarter is then just:

```
Math.ceil(month/3)
```

```js
function getQuarter(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + 'Q' + Math.ceil((date.getMonth()+ 1)/3);
}

function listQuarters(sDate, eDate) {

  // Ensure start is the earlier date;
  if (sDate > eDate) {
    var t = eDate;
    eDate = sDate;
    sDate = t;
  }

  // Copy input start date do don't affect original
  sDate = new Date(sDate);
  
  // Set to 2nd of month so adding months doesn't roll over
  // and not affected by daylight saving
  sDate.setDate(2);

  // Initialise result array with start quarter
  var startQ = getQuarter(sDate);
  var endQ   = getQuarter(eDate);
  var result = [startQ];
  
  // List quarters from start to end
  while (startQ != endQ) {
    sDate.setMonth(sDate.getMonth() + 3);
    startQ = getQuarter(sDate);
    result.push(startQ);
  } 
  
  return result;
}

var start = new Date(2016,0,31);  // 31 Jan 2016
var end   = new Date();           // Today

console.log('Current quater: ' + getQuarter(end));
console.log('Quarter list  : ' + listQuarters(start, end));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a start date and an end date, in a loop increase start date until it equals end date, count quarterchanges:

```js
//A quarter is defined as a fourth of a year
function getQuarter(date) {
  return Math.floor(date.getMonth() / 3);
}
//A quartertimestamp adds the product quarters of the current year to the quartercount
function getQuarterTimestamp(date) {
  return getQuarter(date) + ":" + date.getFullYear();
}
//quartersTillNow calculates how many quarters in the past a date is
function quartersTillNow(origialFrom) {
  //From is a clone of origialFrom
  var from = new Date(origialFrom.getTime());
  //To is today
  var to = new Date();
  //Variable to count number of quarters between
  var quarters = 0;
  //While from is in the past, add month to from
  while (getQuarterTimestamp(from) != getQuarterTimestamp(to)) {
    //newFrom is defined as a clone of from
    var newFrom = new Date(from.getTime());
    //Add a month
    newFrom.setMonth(newFrom.getMonth() + 1);
    //If quarter has changed
    if (getQuarter(newFrom) != getQuarter(from)) {
      //Add a quarter
      quarters++;
    }
    //overwrite from and keep repeat
    from = newFrom;
  }
  //return count of quarters
  return quarters;
}
//TEST
var from = new Date();
from.setFullYear(2000);
console.log(from, "was", quartersTillNow(from), "quarters ago");
```

Comment: Seems to me that for a date 17 years ago, there should have been about 17x4 quarters, or 68 quarters. This answer gives 51. Where did the other 4 years go? I don't understand the logic behind `getQuarter(date) + date.getFullYear() * 4`.

Comment: @RobG You are correct. In the `getQuarter` i should divide by months in a quarter (`3`) not number of quarters (`4`). It is fixed now. `getQuarterTimestamp` meant to get a unique id for each quarter ever. Since there are `4` quarters in a year it should be (`currentQuarter` + `4 times the current year`). I have made another way of generating the ID that hopefully makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't loop through every date, just procedurally adding quarters up to, but not including, the current quarter.

```
function listQuarters(sDate, eDate) {

    //Get the quarter of the current month
    var sQuarter = Math.floor((sDate.getMonth()-1)/3)+1;
    var eQuarter = Math.floor((eDate.getMonth()-1)/3)+1;

    var sYear = sDate.getYear();
    var eYear = eDate.getYear();

    var quarterNames = ['Jan-Feb-Mar', 'Apr-May-Jun', 'Jul-Aug-Sep', 'Oct-Nov-Dec'];
    var quarterList = [];

    while(sQuarter != eQuarter && sYear != eYear) {

        quarterList.push(sYear + ' Q' + quarterNames[sQuarter-1]);

        sQuarter++;

        if(sQuarter > 4) {
            sQuarter = 1;
            sYear++;
        }
    }

    return quarterList;

}
```

Comment: Where is `Int` defined?

Comment: @RobG, sorry, my mistake, I got my languages mixed up. It's supposed to be the integer/floor function, but that's `Math.floor()` in javascript. I'll correct my answer.